# Get DOT graphviz of nested list elements which can contain duplicated nodes

Tags: python, graphviz, decision-tree, dot, pygraphviz

I have a set of nested lists which can be seperated in three groups:

- A (subelements are disjunction, line colors GREEN), e.g.

  ```
  listA = {
  ‘a1’: ['b1', 'a2'],
  ‘a2’: ['c1', 'c2']
   }
  ```
- B (subelements are **ordered** conjunction, line colors ORANGE), e.g.

  ```
  listB = {
  ‘b1’: ['c4', 'c5', 'c7'],
  ‘b2’:['c3', 'b1']
   }
  ```
- C (final elements - leaf nodes)

The function `combinations` itereates through the nested lists and returns all possible combinations (which at the end only contains of elements of type C, so leaf nodes). The function `write_nodes` helps to write the nodes with colored lines. The call `write_nodes('task', inputlist)` is for creating the init node:

```
def write_nodes(node, subnotes):
    for k in subnotes:
        if node in type_a:
            text_file.write("{} -> {} [color=\"green\"]\n".format(node, k)) 
        elif (node in type_b) or (node is 'task'):
            text_file.write("{} -> {} [color=\"orange\"]\n".format(node, k))

write_nodes('task', inputlist)

def combinations(actions):
    if len(actions)==1:
        action= actions[0]
        if action not in type_c:
            root = action
        try:
            actions= type_a[action]
            write_nodes(root, actions)
        except KeyError:
            try:
                actions= type_b[action]
                write_nodes(root, actions)
            except KeyError:
                #action is of type C, the only possible combination is itself
                yield actions
            else:
                #action is of type B (conjunction), combine all the actions
                for combination in combinations(actions):
                    yield combination
        else:
            #action is of type A (disjunction), generate combinations for each action
            for action in actions:
                for combination in combinations([action]):
                    yield combination
    else:
        #generate combinations for the first action in the list
        #and combine them with the combinations for the rest of the list
        action= actions[0]
        for combination in combinations(actions[1:]):
            for combo in combinations([action]):
                yield combo + combination
```

**Example input (ordered conjunction):**

`['a1', 'b2', 'c6']`

**Example result:**

```
['c4', 'c5', 'c7', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c7', 'c6']
['c1', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c7', 'c6']
['c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c7', 'c6']
```

**The result I got from my code:**
[image]
corresponding dot file:

```
task -> a1 [color="orange"]
task -> b2 [color="orange"]
task -> c6 [color="orange"]
b2 -> c3 [color="orange"]
b2 -> b1 [color="orange"]
b1 -> c4 [color="orange"]
b1 -> c5 [color="orange"]
b1 -> c7 [color="orange"]
a1 -> b1 [color="green"]
a1 -> a2 [color="green"]
b1 -> c4 [color="orange"]
b1 -> c5 [color="orange"]
b1 -> c7 [color="orange"]
a2 -> c1 [color="green"]
a2 -> c2 [color="green"]
```

**The result I want (colors are not prior one):** 
[image]

**Questions:**

How can I handle the fact, there there are some duplicated nodes to get a result as mentioned?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you familiar with `graphviz` python package? What have you tried? BTW, It is bad practice to use `try/except` for normal program flow.

Comment: I updated my question, what I have so far. I think _familiar_ is the wrong word, I just know the structure of a dot file. Maybe you can help me, what is a better way to avoid the try/except.

Answer (score 2):

## Duplicate nodes problem

To avoid the duplicate nodes problem you should name each node with a unique name and use a `label` for the displayed name. For example change:

```
b2 -> b1 [color="orange"]
b1 -> c4 [color="orange"]
b1 -> c5 [color="orange"]
b1 -> c7 [color="orange"]
a1 -> b1 [color="green"]
b1 -> c4 [color="orange"]
b1 -> c5 [color="orange"]
b1 -> c7 [color="orange"]
```

to:

```
b21 [label="b2"]
b11 [label="b1"]
b21 -> b11 [color="orange"]
c41 [label="c4"]
b11 -> c41 [color="orange"]
c51 [label="c5"]
b11 -> c51 [color="orange"]
c71 [label="c7"]
b11 -> c71 [color="orange"]
a11 [label="a2"]
b12 [label="b1"]
a11 -> b12 [color="green"]
c42 [label="c4"]
b12 -> c42 [color="orange"]
c52 [label="c5"]
b12 -> c52 [color="orange"]
c72 [label="c7"]
b12 -> c72 [color="orange"]
```

Which produce:
[image: res]

## Avoid `try/except` flow

It's better to use `if/else` and not `try/except` for normal program flow. For example instead of:

```
    try:
        actions= type_a[action]
        write_nodes(root, actions)
    except KeyError:
        #do whatever you do
```

use:

```
    actions = type_a.get(action, None) #if the key doesn't exists assign None
    if actions:
        write_nodes(root, actions)
    else:
        #do whatever you do
```

## Graphviz python package

You can use the [`graphviz` python package](http://matthiaseisen.com/articles/graphviz/) instead of writing the dot file yourself.